# Webscraping with Java Jsoup not extracting data on server

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm working with webscrapers with java using jsoup, i'm having an issue with one of them because the data from the site not being extracted when the scraper runs on the server, however it's does work in a local PC.

I tried to use a proxy to check if the domain of the server was banned from the website i'm scraping but that wasn't the problem.

What's even more confusing to me, is that the webscraper extracts data from the website but not a particular type of data (for example, i'm scraping a website where you can book hotels, i can extract comments from the users, the calification they gave to that hotel, etc etc. but not the prices of the hotel for that day)

i already checked that:

- the html/css from the website  haven't changed
- i have response 200 from their servers
- the prices of the hotels are getting extracted when i test the program locally but not in the server
- i use different user agents each time

Anyone who has worked doing webscrapers has any idea of what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely the prices of the hotel, or the content that you are not able to scrape, are **generated by JavaScript**.

Jsoup does **not** support JavaScript, it will only get you the **plain html** that was received from the server, before being manipulated by JavaScript.

The best way to verify this is to simply `print` the html that was received with Jsoup and check the content. Something like this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
System.out.println(doc.html());
```

Comment: Actually i do get the hotel prices, the thing doesn't work the same when the program runs on the server